# Laravel 5.3 KCFinder integration routing

Tags: php, laravel-5, ckeditor, laravel-5.3, kcfinder

I have a problem with KCFinder for CKEditor and Laravel 5.3, and I hope someone can help me with that.

At the moment I have my KCFinder files in `public/kcfinder` folder. But when I'm trying to integrate these to CKEditor and access the files, under "`/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images&CKEditor=ckeditor&CKEditorFuncNum=0&langCode=ru`", I get an error from Laravel. It tries to execute this link as one of the routes -  `Route::get('/{category}/{subcat}', ['as' => 'producers_by_subcat', 'uses' => 'CatalogController@producersBySubcat']);`, so I get an error. This route is in the end of `web.php` routing file.

Any ideas how to fix this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you find the solution?

Comment: Sadly, I do not.